# Grammaticality of "What is there there?"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, there-is

If someone says

> I am going to the market

I may ask

> What is there at the market?

If someone says

> I am going to the bookstore

I may ask

> What is there at the bookstore?

If someone says

> I am going there

is it then correct to say

> What is **there there**?

It seems correct following the pattern, but it sounds weird.

Comment: Actually, your first two sentences don't sound all too good to me either. _What's at the market?_ or _What's at the library?_ sounds better to my ears.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Note that the two "there"s are likely to be pronounced differently, with the first one unstressed and with a reduced vowel.

Comment: *Grammatical* is not the same as *would be commonly (or indeed  ever) employed by a native speaker*.

Comment: One of Gertrude Stein's most famous lines is the statement "there is no there there." From [Wikipedia's article on Stein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertrude_Stein#.22There_is_no_there_there.22): "She took us to see her granddaughter who was teaching in the Dominican convent in San Raphael, we went across the bay on a ferry, that had not changed but Goat Island might just as well not have been there, anyway what was the use of my having come from Oakland it was not natural to have come from there yes write about it if I like or anything if I like but not there, **there is no there there**."

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, but I'd use *there there* there ... ;)

Comment: Sometimes things sound weird but they are still grammatical. Then it becomes a style choice to reword if desired.

Comment: @oerkelens: Changing the intonation, it makes more sense. _"What's there [pause] at the market?"_ Essentially, you added "at the market" to elaborate on what you meant when you said "there". Sort of a tautology, but with increasing levels of specificity. (which means that "there there" still doesn't make sense, as it's not adding anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sentence is perfectly fine. The two "there"s here are different types of word. The first is a type of Noun Phrase. The second is a Locative Preposition (some people think it's a Locative Adverb). It indicates a location.

The first *there* is the Subject of the question. The second is a locative Adjunct  ( - where *Subject* and *Adjunct* are different functions in the sentence).

With questions like this, the *Wh-* word moves to the front of the sentence. If the *Wh*- word is not the Subject of the sentence, then the Subject of the sentence inverts with the Auxiliary Verb. In this case the auxiliary is the Verb *BE*. For all  questions like this, there is a non-inverted form - consider it an ugly sister - where the *Wh-* word stays in the same position it would be in in a normal sentence. It's sometimes called an *in-situ* question. The in-situ question for the Original Poster's example is:

- There is *what* there?

Here we can clearly see the Noun Phrase *There* sitting in the Subject position in the sentence. We call it a "Dummy" Subject here because it has no lexical meaning. The Verb *is* is where we expect to see it, right after the Subject. *What*, the internal Complement of *is*, appears in its normal position after the Verb. Lastly the Locative Adjunct *there* takes up its usual position at the end of the sentence, where we expect Adjuncts to be.

This all goes to show that the Original Poster's example is well formed, and has all the correct parts that we should expect it to have.

Comment: +1, this sort of topic, which involves existentials, does come up a lot. :)

Comment: @Greybeard Subject is not a semantic term, it’s a structural one. That’s why we can have dummy subjects like *it* and *there* etc

Comment: *The first there is the Subject of the question.* No, It is not. It remains an adverb of existence. "What is there there?" = "What exists in that place?"

Comment: @Greybeard I know it’s confusing when you first find out about it. Try looking it up in a modern grammar book. E.g. Oxford Modern English Grammar. Expletive *there* has a different pronunciation and entirely different grammatical properties to locative *there*. Have you heard of subject auxiliary inversion? It’s when the subject and the auxiliary swap places. It’s how we make yes/no questions like ***Is there** a God?*

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I refuse to be confused. "There" is an adverb. **there *is* a dog -> there *are* dogs**: the verb changes because the subject (dog/dogs) changes - subject verb inversion after an adverb has a long tradition in English: currently it is mainly concerned with locative and existential adverbs. "Here is a cat - a cat is here."  I am aware of the properties of "there". -- "It" can be a (dummy) subject - it has a referent. "There" cannot be a subject.

Comment: @Greybeard 1) *Here is a cat* is not subject auxiliary inversion, it's subject-dependent inversion. 2) Dummy *it* has not referent. That's why it's called dummy it! 3) Get with the grammar! This is elementary stuff.

Comment: @Greybeard [See here: UCL Internet Grammar of English](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/unusual.htm). Here is a [Wikipedia introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_grammar#%22There%22). Here's [an introduction for grown-ups from Pompeu Fabra University](https://www.upf.edu/documents/2979964/0/chapter69.pdf/01d497c3-f1d8-498e-af7b-976ced709c29). See the [first page of this academic paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4179283). Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 4):

"What's there there?" is grammatical.

Here's why.

"There is a book."
It means the existence of a book in a certain place, which is here not stated.

"There is a book there."
This means, "You got a book there (here, a place)."

So the first "there" in your example is just about existence; the second the place.

Comment: They have different names: 'existential there' (compare French il y a) and 'locative / directional there' (= French là).

Answer (score -1):

Actually, following the pattern it should be "what is there at there". Without "at" the pattern is "what is there the bookstore".

Comment: *There* = **At** *the bookstore*.